# Pandas replace countries not in list of nationalities with 'other' using str replace

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column of countries that reviewers are from. I want to replace all of the countries that are NOT in my nationalities list with "other".

I created the following code but it will not run. I get this error..

ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (51575,), (9,))

```
nationalities = ['United Kingdom', 'United States of America', 'Australia', 'Ireland', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Netherlands', 'Germany', 'Canada' ]
sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'] = sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'].replace(np.where(sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'] != nationalities), 'Other')
```

Sample Input:

```
sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'] = np.array([[' Latvia ', ' Israel ', ' Lebanon ', ' Azerbaijan ',
       ' Kazakhstan ', ' Iraq ', ' Thailand ', ' Denmark ', ' Bulgaria ',
       ' Luxembourg ', ' Jordan ', ' Kenya ', ' Iceland ', ' Estonia ',
       ' Serbia ', ' Malta ', ' Cyprus ', ' Greece ', ' South Africa ',
       ' Croatia ', ' Oman ', ' Bahrain ', ' Finland ', ' Singapore ',
       ' Malaysia ', ' Portugal ', ' Yemen ', ' Bangladesh ', ' Sudan ',
       ' Libya ', ' Palestinian Territory ', ' Lithuania ',
       ' Philippines ', ' Hong Kong ', ' ', ' Dominican Republic ',
       ' Armenia ', ' Slovakia ', ' Tunisia ', ' Chile ', ' Mauritius ',
       ' Nepal ', ' Peru ', ' Ghana ', ' Montenegro ', ' Jersey ',
       ' Morocco ', ' Andorra ', ' Sri Lanka ', ' Argentina ',
       ' Puerto Rico ', ' Honduras ', ' Indonesia ', ' Abkhazia Georgia ',
       ' Ukraine ', ' Mongolia ', ' Taiwan ', ' Georgia ',
       ' Bosnia and Herzegovina ', ' Montserrat ', ' Uruguay ', ' Syria ',
       ' Jamaica ', ' Angola ', ' Gibraltar ', ' Zambia '])
```

Output:

```
sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'] = np.array(['United Kingdom', 
'United States of America', 
'Australia', 'Ireland', 
'United Arab Emirates', 
'Saudi Arabia', 
'Netherlands', 'Germany', 
'Canada', 'Other'
])
```

I can run a for loop but it's computationally heavy. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample input an the expected output

Comment: please update your post. Also post real python code to create a dataframe. Also remember to post the expected OUTPUT

Comment: Done! Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: You are using a dataframe, right? So please post the code to get a dataframe, not a list! Also, we're interested in a MINIMAL working example, there's no need to post all your data

Comment: Is that better? I am sorry but pandas is returning the items in that column as a list when I call the unique method on it. I don't know another way to enter it without just putting in my entire csv.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `str.replace` for this.

```
sample_hotel_df.loc[~sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'].isin(nationalities), 'Reviewer_Nationality'] = "other"
```

Comment: Hey there! That converted everything to other unfortunately. I want the countries in the list "nationalities" to still be there. Everything else should be other.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your CSV file (data.csv):

```
Reviewer_Nationality
Latvia
Israel
United States of America
Lebanon
United Kingdom 
Australia
```

You can read it by using pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> rev_nat = pd.read_csv('data.csv')['Reviewer_Nationality'].to_list()
```

Then you can filter the nationalities in this way:

```
>>> nat = ['United Kingdom', 'United States of America', 'Australia', 'Ireland']
>>> result = list(set(n if n in nat else 'Other' for n in rev_nat))
```

The final result is

```
['Other', 'United States of America', 'Australia']
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the help. That seems to convert everything to other though. I want the countries in nationalities to be there... all other countries should be other.

Comment: @ElizabethMiller This is exactly what my code does :)

Comment: @ElizabethMiller I updated my answer. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably :

```py
ser = sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality']
sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'] = ser.where(ser.isin(nationalities), 'Other')
```

Anyway, use `ser.isin(lst)` and `~ser.isin(lst)` in your filters instead of `==` and `!=` that's why you had an error.

`==` and `!=` are for a single element comparison

Edit :

Yes it works :)

But :

1. Your sample Series has no country that shouldn't be 'Other' according to your list...
2. All your countries have trailing and leading spaces. So you should clean it with .str.strip()

So this should work, even with your data :

```py
ser = sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'].str.strip()
sample_hotel_df['Reviewer_Nationality'] = ser.where(ser.isin(nationalities), 'Other')
```

Comment: Thank you! But it's changing everything to "other".